# MySQL Connector/NET Output Parameter Returning NULL

Tags: mysql, .net, mysql-connector, connector-net

Using the following code:

```
MySqlParameter curParam = new MySqlParameter("var", MySqlDbType.Int32);
curParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
oCmd.Parameters.Add(curParam);
```

With the following Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(OUT var INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, 2, 3;
    SELECT 27 INTO var;
END
$$
```

Running this from the console returns "27":

```
CALL testProc(@i);
SELECT @i;
```

However in .NET, when executing the query (when the connection is still open), curParam.value returns NULL.

The stored procedure otherwise returns the correct results. Additionally, when running the Stored Procedure directly in the console, the output param returns correctly as well.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Edited to include SQL

Comment: Can you add all the .Net code you are using?

Comment: I cannot, as it is part of a much larger application. However, the stored procedure is called using oCmd.ExecuteReader(). All input parameters are passed and read correctly with the code and I can assure you that it is fully functional and correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

output parameters will only be populated after the reader is closed. when does your code execute the reader compared to when you get the parameter value?

Comment: output parameters will only be populated after the reader is closed.  when does your code execute the reader compared to when you get the parameter value?

Comment: That was the issue. Works without the question mark. Please update the answer and I'll accept it.